# Run RabbitMQ in a separate server

Tags: rabbitmq, producer

I have a separate server where I've installed RabbitMQ. I have set `NODE_IP_ADDRESS` to be `0.0.0.0` in `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` so it can be accessible from outside. And also enabled the port 5672 in the firewall `ufw allow 5672`.
But still, when I try to produce a message I get

`Could not connect to the AMQP server. Please verify the provided DSN.`

Here is the DNS string i'm using to connect ( Symfony app )

`MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://rabbitmq_user:rabbitmq_pswd@ip_of_the_server:5672/%2f`

btw, the web interface works just fine

Does anyone know what could be the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can we get example DSN string you using in your app?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after displaying the real exception message, I figured out that the user was not allowed to login to the vhost `/`